# UNNotificationRequest with repeat notification trigger option triggers at the start

Tags: ios, swift, localnotification

I am setting up my local notification using the following code. The issue I am facing is that it triggers the "will present" delegate call back just after the execution of this code and don't wait for the interval. i.e. 2 minutes. then trigger again after 2 minutes as required. I am new to this.

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
center.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()

let message = String(format: "No hit since %d minutes", notificationInterval!)
content.body = message
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()


let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: TimeInterval(2 * 60), repeats: true)

let request  = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "liveSessionLocalNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)
// Schedule the notification.

center.add(request) { (error) in

}
```

Comment: It's strange unless you have other request also going on parallel.

Comment: It worked fine on other devices and simulator. Only showing this behavior on my iPhone 6 Plus.